# JavaScript returns incorrect date value after using setHours()

Tags: javascript

This is pretty self explanatory if you compare the two date values that are returned. If the second value is also a date, but for some reason printed in a strange way, can I somehow convert it to similar format to the first value, so I know that the time is set correctly?

```js
const date = new Date()
console.log(date)
console.log(date.setHours(5))
```

Comment: You're logging the value `setHours` returns. Separate the code: `date.setHours(5); console.log(date);`.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to set the hour then you can `log` the date with correct format. Because `setHours()` is a function that **returns the number of milliseconds and the updated date**. The default date will be formatted according to **universal” UTC time**. IST will be 6hrs behind hence if you will `setHours(12)` then it will be 6pm in IST and if you will `setHours(n)` then it will be `n+6` in 24hrs format.

```js
let date = new Date()
console.log(date)
date.setHours(5)
console.log(date)

//OR

date = new Date(date.setHours(5))
console.log(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var date = new Date()
console.log(date)
date = new Date(date.setHours(5))
console.log(date)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).